# url encoding in python and sqlite web app

Tags: python, url, web-applications

am new to python and am trying to build a blog kind of web app, my major problem is that I want the title of the each post to be its link which I would store in my database. I am using the serial number of each post as the url, but it doesn't meet my needs. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used a *urlencode* flag with the title. Something like `{{title l urlencode}}`. P.s the single *l* is a pipe.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your right what you are looking for is to store a slug. There's a package that can help you with this.

https://github.com/un33k/python-slugify

Hope it helps!